# Refused to connect when accessing phpmyadmin on docker container

Tags: phpmyadmin, docker-compose, jhipster

I use docker-compose to setup my application with below app.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    hdback-app:
        image: xxxx:0.0.3
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/sample?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
            - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=sample-elasticsearch:9300
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    db:
        extends:
            file: mysql.yml
            service: db
    nginx:
        extends:
            file: nginx.yml
            service: nginx
    hdback-elasticsearch:
        extends:
            file: elasticsearch.yml
            service: hdback-elasticsearch
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
```

The application is installed on Centos 7, the nginx.yml is as below:

```
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.14.0
        volumes:
            - ./../www:/usr/share/nginx/html
            - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

And the site.conf is as below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://www.sample.com:8080/api;
    }
    location /management {
        proxy_pass http://www.sample.com:8080/management;
    }
    location /v2 {
       proxy_pass http://www.sample.com:8080/v2;
    }
    location /swagger-ui {
        proxy_pass http://www.sample.com:8080/swagger-ui;
    }
    location /swagger-resources {
        proxy_pass http://www.sample.com:8080/swagger-resources;
    }
}
```

When I up the application, www.sample.com works, that is, port 80 works, however, when I want to access phpmyadmin, the browser says:

```
sample.com refused to connect
```

I disable the firewall, and ensure the port 8081 is listening, below is when I issue:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
5a18390de5e1        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin                                    "/run.sh supervisord…"    24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         80/tcp, 9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp         docker_phpmyadmin_1
1de715bb735d        nginx:1.14.0                                             "nginx -g 'daemon of…"    24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                               docker_nginx_1
6b748cb592ec        elasticsearch:2.4.6                                      "/docker-entrypoint.…"    24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   docker_hdback-elasticsearch_1
dd3de12c3ff4        mysql:5.7.20                                             "docker-entrypoint.s…"    24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                           docker_db_1
c0ad30aabd3c        xxxx:0.0.3   "/bin/sh -c 'echo \"T…"   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                           docker_hdback-app_1
```

I have spent almost half day to find solution but no luck, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refuses to connect because you connect from port 8081 of the host to port 8081 of the container, while phpmyadmin is served at port 80, as you can see [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/~/dockerfile/)

So map it this way:

```
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
        - db
    ports:
        - 8081:80
```

and it should work

Comment: thanks, will try it later, just one question, because the port for nginx is 80:80, if config phpmyadmin port as 8081:80, is there conflicts between two 80? or each container can have its own port set?

Comment: The inner ports won't conflict. The convention is always host:container